# I want to create a custom keyboard in android

Tags: android

and i  looked /read the sample  sofkeyboard code and tried to run it on my emulator and on my device  .The console shows that the app is installed but i can't locate it on my desktop to use it but it shows the name in the application location

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-press any input field. There should appear something like "Input Method". Choose your app. The default keyboard should disappear and your soft keyboard example will be used instead.

Comment: well my app name is not appearing in "Input Method" on my device there are only two options Swype and Android Keyboard plz help.

Comment: @VicentePlata I have create custom keyboard that works fine when  set as default keyboard but i want to set in my application how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is of any relevance now but I had the same issue recently and you can just go to Settings --> Language and Input --> it should list your keyboard there. Uncheck the existing default keyboard and check your keyboard and you should be good to go.